# Problems redirecting to "pretty" permalinks (wordpress in Subdirectory)

Tags: permalinks, 404-error, htaccess

I've got problems getting pretty permalinks to work.

When changing the permalinks (e.g. to month/name), my .htaccess (in the wordpress directory - there is another one one level up) is changed like this:

```
AddType x-mapp-php5 .php
AddHandler x-mapp-php5 .php

# BEGIN WordPress
<IfModule mod_rewrite.c>
RewriteEngine On
RewriteBase /wordpress/
RewriteRule ^index\.php$ - [L]
RewriteCond %{REQUEST_FILENAME} !-f
RewriteCond %{REQUEST_FILENAME} !-d
RewriteRule . /wordpress/index.php [L]
</IfModule>

# END WordPress
```

But I still get 404s when trying to access an existing page.

My blog is in the /wordpress/ subdirectory, not sure if that may be a problem. The URLs are both set to  `http://<my domain>/wordpress` which is where my wordpress files are located.

Any ideas what I can do, where I can see the results of the rewrite or anything else that would help me to track down the problem?

Thanks in advance!

Comment: Is the `.htaccess` in the same directory as WordPress? And what are the two URLs you have set in Options - General (WordPress address & Site address)?

Comment: I've added the information you requested. Hope it helps in tracking down the issue!

Answer (score 1, accepted):

I've finally managed to track down the cause of the problem .. it was a Plugin that seems to have issues (Top Level Categories). I've looked into their documentation, but there is no indication that I would run into that problem. Hmmmm ...

At least it's working now!

Answer (score 2):

Save your existing `.htaccess` file by renaming it to `backup.htaccess` & then re-save your permalinks which will create a new `.htaccess` file. That solves issues most of the time.

Comment: This didn't change anything. (And I wouldn't know why it should as long as wordpress was able to write the .htaccess file.)

Comment: @IronGoofy Does the default permalinks work? Also you shouldn't be using a plugin which has issues with WP 3.1, take a look here - http://wordpress.org/support/topic/troubleshooting-wordpress-31-master-list?replies=16

Comment: Thanks for the suggestion with the plugins, that helped me to try out some more things which finally lead to the solution of my problem (see my own answer).

Comment: @IronGoofy you can mark your answer as the accepted answer, add any details that you feel might help someone who comes looking for the same problem.

Comment: Will do, but I have to wait until tomorrow before I can accept my own answer.